# Match string in column and sum corresponding rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have this issue that I'm trying to solve with VBA.

**Table**

[image: Table Example]

There is only 1 sheet in the workbook.

**Expected Solution**

I'm trying to perform a string search for **column A**, such that if it is A75X (where X is any number), I want to sum up the corresponding A75X values under **column C**, and replace the A75 column C blank with the summed value.

**Expected Output**

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Do you need VBA? Sounds like you can use SUMIF with a wildcard to do this.

Comment: Yep I can solve it with `=SUMIFS(C:C, A:A,"A75*")` but I'll need the VBA code as this is just a small snippet of what I'm trying to achieve...

Comment: `ws.Evaluate("=SUMIFS(C:C, A:A,""" & stringHere & "*"")")` where ws is a reference to your sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in a new VBA module:

```
Sub CalculateFinancials()
        Dim aCells As Range
        Dim aCell As Range
        Dim cellValue As String
        Dim foreignCurrency As Double
        Dim nationalCurrency As Double

        Set aCells = Range("A:A")

        For Each aCell In aCells
            cellValue = aCell.Value
            If InStr(cellValue, "A75") <> 0  And cellValue <> "A75" Then
                foreignCurrency = foreignCurrency + Cells(aCell.Row, 3)
            End If
            If InStr(cellValue, "A71") <> 0  And cellValue <> "A71" Then
                nationalCurrency = nationalCurrency + Cells(aCell.Row, 3)
            End If
        Next aCell
        Cells(13, 3) = foreignCurrency
        Cells(4, 3) = nationalCurrency
    End Sub
```